cordova-diagnostic-plugin: cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAuthorized Always returns NOT_REQUESTED Android 14
I am using cordova-diagnostic-plugin to ask the customer to allow their location access. But it always returns NOT_REQUESTED. I think there is a problem with my s. Here is the list of my I can't find what is missing
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>


cordova-diagnostic-plugin is a diagnostic plugin, and the isLocationAuthorized is made for checking if the access to location has been requested. It is not made to request access to the location.
You should consider a plugin such as https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions to check/request for permissions instead.
